# Load order of NinjectModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have installed the `Ninject.Web.Common` NuGet package in my ASP.NET MVC project:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        Bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        Bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }        
}
```

Note that I used `kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())` to automatically register my bindings when I derive from `NinjectModule`. However I have dependencies that need to be resolved inside a `NinjectModule`:

```
public class NinjectModuleA : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ILogger>().To<Log4NetLogger>().InSingletonScope();
    }
}

public class NinjectModuleB : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IRepository>()
          .To<Repository>()
          .WithConstructorArgument(typeof(ILogger), Kernel.Get<ILogger>())
          .InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Somehow `NinjectModuleB` was loaded before `NinjectModuleA`, which gave me an `ActivationException`:

> Error activating ILogger
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>   1) Request for ILogger

which is understandable as the binding for `ILogger` wasn't available when `NinjectB.Load` was called. Is there any way I can tell Ninject that `NinjectModuleA` must be loaded before `NinjectModuleB`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the IoC incorrectly.
The idea is, that `ILogger` is injected into the ctor of the object. Except from special cases, you don't need to specifiy which constructor argument is to be used.
By default, ninject will look for a suitable constructor and try to resolve all the constructor arguments. So you don't need an `WithConstructorArgument(...)` at all.
Rather all you need is this:

```
public class Repository
{
    public Repository(ILogger logger) { }
}

Bind<Ilogger>().To(... some binding...);
Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>();

IRepository repository = kernel.Get<IRepository>(); // creates an instance of `Repository` and injects an `ILogger` - which is to be resolved as specified by the `Bind<Ilogger>.To...` binding.
```

---

If you absolutely need to control the load order, you will have to implement that part yourself, and then use `IKernel.Load<T> : where T : INinjectModule` or `IKernel.Load(INinjectModule module)`.

However, you should, whenever possible, adapt your design so that these dependencies are not necessary. For you current case, all you've got to do is, replacing

```
WithConstructorArgument(typeof(ILogger), Kernel.Get<ILogger>())
```

by

```
WithConstructorArgument(typeof(ILogger), ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ILogger>());
```

but, as already said, you can get rid of the `WithConstructorArgument` entirely.

Comment: Yes you are right...must have forgotten my coffee today, thanks!